# Customize Color Visualization: Geochart

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, colors, customization

I'm making a customize Visualization: Geochart. I have figured out how to change the background color, but I'm trying to change the highlighted color. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
        var options = {
        backgroundColor: '#333',
        };
```

Currently I'm trying:

```
colorAxis: {colors: ['404040', '8f2424']},
```

Thanks

Comment: what you mean by highlighted color? you mean like mouse over color?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the mark feature something similar to this.Hope this helps.

```
 mark {
background-color: yellow;
color: black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what do you really mean about "highlighted color" but if you mean you want to change the color on hover you can try this on css

```css
#yourcontainerdivid path:hover { fill: #404040; stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.5; }  
#yourcontainerdivid rect:hover { fill: transparent;}
```